# how to use owl carousel sync with RTL direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

i want to use owl carousel sync with RTL direction but not working

i wrote following style to fixed this problem bug my sync owl carousel not working :

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item{
   float: right !important;
}
```

what to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rtl: true

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:5
    }
}
})
```